# R: How to match values within column 1, and assign adjacent values from column 2 to lower in column 2

Tags: r

I have 3 columns.  The first column is complete, but the second and third columns are incomplete, and I want to complete them based on existing values in all 3 columns.  Here is an example:

```
number  a   b
1       Q   V
2       R   W
3       S   X
4       T   Y
5       U   Z
3       S   X
2       R   W
4       T   Y
1       Q   V
5       U   Z
4       
1       
5       
3       
2       
2       
4       
3       
5       
1
```

What I need to do is go to the first empty value in column "a", look at the value in column "number" (4), find the values of "a" and "b" that correspond to "number" (4), and then insert those values into the columns "a" and "b" -- and then move on to the next missing value.

I've come upon one solution using two dataframes.  One dataframe called "df" is the original table shown at the beginning of this post, and the second dataframe (called "df2") is a key:

```
number a b
1      Q V
2      R W
3      S X
4      T Y
5      U Z
3      S X
2      R W
4      T Y
1      Q V
5      U Z
```

Then, I am able to fill in values to df using values from df1 using

```
df$a <- df2$a[ match(df$number, df2$number)]
df$b <- df2$b[ match(df$number, df2$number)]
```

which gives the new df as

```
 number a b
1       Q V
2       R W
3       S X
4       T Y
5       U Z
3       S X
2       R W
4       T Y
1       Q V
5       U Z
4       T Y
1       Q V
5       U Z
3       S X
2       R W
2       R W
4       T Y
3       S X
5       U Z
1       Q V
```

This seems to work for me!  However, I have a few outstanding issues/questions:

1) Is there a more elegant or efficient way to do this, preferably using just the single dataframe df?

2) To match "numbers", does this method just use the first instance of a match in that column?

3) Is there a good way to test that existing "a" and "b" values have been assigned correctly (i.e. each instance of the same "number" has the same "a" and "b".  This is related to question #2 directly above.

Thanks for any advice on this!

Comment: I would say the test needs to first determine that all rows with the same "Number" have the same "a" and "b" values. After that check  correct code will take over. You can use `duplicated` for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks I will look into duplicated.  Sorry I missed this, I must've been editing my post when you posted this.  Thanks, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think DWin has the right idea here, but there is no reason to create the extra data frame.  The 'match' function finds only the first match, so we don't have to worry about the rest of the data frame.  You can abbreviate his code like so:

```
data[data$a=="",] <- data[match(data$number[data$a==""], data$number), ]
```

And that's it.

In plain English, this code says, "For the set rows missing a value for 'a', find the first row in the column 'number' that matches 'number' in the missing rows, and write the whole matching row into the old row."

Comment: Is there a way to use this same method but save the result at a new dataframe (for example, data2)?  I tried substituting "data2" for data on the left-hand side of your code, but it gave me an error.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to preserve the old data frame, just copy it first.  `data_old <- data` or some such.  In fact, this is good practice in general.

Answer (score 1):

Build two data.frames:

```
dat <- read.table(text="number  a   b
1       Q   V
2       R   W
3       S   X
4       T   Y
5       U   Z", header=TRUE)
bigger <-read.table(text="number  a   b
1       Q   V
2       R   W
3       S   X
4       T   Y
5       U   Z
3       S   X
2       R   W
4       T   Y
1       Q   V
5       U   Z
4       
1       
5       
3       
2       
2       
4       
3       
5       
1", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

Then pull in matching rows from the samller one to fill the missing data:

```
bigger[bigger$a=="", ] <- dat[match( bigger$number[bigger$a==""], dat$number), ]
> bigger
   number a b
1       1 Q V
2       2 R W
3       3 S X
4       4 T Y
5       5 U Z
6       3 S X
7       2 R W
8       4 T Y
9       1 Q V
10      5 U Z
11      4 T Y
snipped output
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I believe I ventured onto a similar solution as well, and was editing my original post as you posted this.  However, somehow your solution does this using a single line of code, as opposed to my 2 lines (one for each of columns "a" and "b".  Thanks for this, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you tell us how will you feed those data in, for those who will answer to be more precise in their answers.

An idea of the solution is presented in python.

```
class Sequence(object):       

    def __init__(self):

        self.D = {
                    1 : ['Q','V'],
                    2 : ['R','W'],
                    3 : ['S','X'],
                    4 : ['T','Y'],
                    5 : ['U','Z'],
                 }


    def add(self, val, *a_b):

        self.D[val] = [a_b[0],a_b[1]]


    def find(self, seed):

        ##  Add all the enteries you want to add in this dict.
        return self.D[seed]

    def ret_all(self):
        return self.D

# Initialize    
s = Sequence()

# Add new item
s.add(9,['M','V'])

# Find by index
cols = s.find(3)
print 'a col: ', cols[0]
print 'b col: ', cols[1]

# Show all the list
All = s.ret_all()

for i,v in All.items():
    print i, [v for x in v]
```

Let me know if that what you want.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help.  I will be feeding these data into R using a command like data <- read.table("C:/data_file.csv,header=T,sep=',').  Please excuse me if this is hard to read, I can't seem to figure out how to insert code or to start a new line in this comment.  And user1317221_G is correct, I am working in R and don't know python, so a solution in R would be best.  Thanks again for your advice!

Comment: You are welcome, and I know it is tagged in R, but I thought an idea written in any language might be of a help, may be another look on my code might give you an insight on how to solve the problem on your own :))

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem understanding the python code.  Also, I do not understand why there isn't a column for "number", or why the code isn't matching "number" values, which is what I think I need to do (?).  Thanks though, I appreciate it.